# How to correctly handle date formats that needs i18n

Tags: datetime, i18n-l10n

Suppose you have a [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format that looks like this: `"Some text Y-m-d other text H:i"`. Please ignore that the text needs some escaping.

What is the correct way of outputting this in a i18n friendly way?
I see that format_date attempts to do some sort of translation work, but I don't understand entirely what.

My best guess:

```
implode(' ', array(
  t('Some text'),
  format_date($timestamp, NULL, 'Y-m-d'),
  t('other text'),
  format_date($timestamp, NULL, 'H:i'),
);`
```

Is this the correct/best way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$text = t("Some text @date more text @time", array(
  '@date' => format_date($timestamp, NULL, 'Y-m-d'),
  '@time' => format_date($timestamp, NULL, 'H:i'),
));
```

More info at:

- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7
- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7

Comment: Doh! Much better, though I learned one cannot use format_date the way I do, so that part needs to be changed.

Comment: try format_date($timestamp, 'custom', 'Y-m-d')

Comment: I had misread the docs, good catch. In this context, do you know if there an advantage to using format_date over date?

Comment: not really, only code style, it's the way you format a date in Drupal. If you use format_date and want to change the output you just have to change the parameters, not the function.